# Pass string to a shell script through CGI

Tags: html, shell, cgi

I'd like to pass a string that user submits in a simple HTML form, just like the following one, to a shell script.
I haven't been able to find the answer so far. I'd appreciate any hints.

```
<form method="post" action="http://example.com/cgi-bin/echo.sh"> 
<input type="text" name="Text" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And a shell script should print the value it captured.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo '<html>'
echo '<head>'
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">'
echo '<title>Echoing argument</title>'
echo '</head>'
echo '<body>'
echo $1
echo '</body>'
echo '</html>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This article](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/BashShellCgi.html) helped to figure it out.
I had to add `set $QUERY_STRING` line before `echo $1`.

Comment: `echo "$QUERY_STRING"` instead of `set $QUERY_STRING; echo $1`